# How can I bind the content of an array proxy to values from another object?

Tags: ember.js

I have some data like this:

```
var organizations = Ember.ArrayProxy.create({
    content: [{
        // organization model data here
        contacts: [{
            // contact model data here
        }]
    }]
});
```

I would like to create an ArrayProxy that aggregates all of the contacts in my organizations object. Something like this:

```
var contacts = Ember.ArrayProxy.extend({
    _organizations: organizations,

    content: function() {
        // return a flat array of contacts (I know how to do this part)
    }.property('_organizations.@each.contacts').readOnly()
});
```

Trying the above gives errors which I assume are because I ArrayProxy doesn't like it's content being extended like this. What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: Just a thought, can we populate the content of contacts on init??

Comment: I could do that, but then if I edit the contact on the organization changes wouldn't be reflected by the aggregate ArrayProxy.

Comment: How about adding an observer and updating the content then. Actually what you've got here should have been doing same but since its causing an issue, it is like doing things manually!

Comment: organizations.on('@each.contacts', update_contacts) - Then I would need the organizations to know about the contacts directly which I'd rather avoid.